# Calculating the depth of nodes in force layout in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am making collapsible layout using d3.js.With my reference to the following code I want to calculate the depth(level) of the clicked node by using depth attribute but I am getting it as undefined. Is there another way to calculate depth??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/70qy8ps6/6/

Comment: Where in the code are you accessing the depth?

Comment: in the starting of the click method

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work please?

Comment: function click(d){ console.log("depth",d,depth);} //its giving depth undefined

Comment: Ah, the force layout doesn't set `depth`, only the tree layout does that. You'll have to compute the depth yourself.

Comment: Any idea or reference how to compute that in force layout as i have the dynamic data,couldnot add it as an attribute either.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate depth of each node inside the `flatten` method as shown below.

```
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;  
    function recurse(node, depth) {     
        node.depth = depth;
        if (node.children) 
            node.children.forEach(function(n){  
                recurse(n,node.depth+1); 
            });
        if (!node.id) 
            node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }
    recurse(root,0);
    return nodes;
}
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70qy8ps6/9/)

Comment: How to filter this function. I want to display the node which is having size greater than 4000 with its parent.